# Why is require module in JavaScript not able to import the fs library?

Tags: javascript, require

The javascript code is as follows:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function init() {
     alert("Done!");
}

init();
```

While executing the Javascript code, I am not able to get the alert `Done!` on my webpage. On further analysis I came to a conclusion that it is most probably because the `require` statement is not working (there was an alert when I commented the require statement). Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` is not available in the browser but is used in NodeJS. If you want to use it in your browser, you'll need a building tool like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/).

By the way, the [File System](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) package is available in NodeJS only.